# Nested loop based on user input in Java

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Is it possible to make nested loop based on user input in Java? For example, if the user inputs 3, then there are 3 loops that are nested (3 levels of loop). If it's possible, could you show me how?

I needed it to generate every possibilities of something. Every loop happens twice. So there are 2^n possibilities.

Thanks for the big help.

**EDIT**
I haven't coded the looping calculation part yet because I'm still trying to figure out the algorithm. 
**Kriteria.java**

```
public class Kriteria {

    String name;
    int min, max;
    double lowMembership, highMembership;
public Kriteria(String name, int min, int max,low,high) {
        this.name = name;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.lowMembership = low;
        this.highMembership = high;
    }

}
```

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Kriteria> listKriteria = new ArrayList();

//later on the user can decide how many kriteria he wanted and create them            
    Kriteria kriteria1,kriteria2,kriteria3;

    kriteria1 = new Kriteria("Kriteria 1", 1, 10, 4,3,5);
    listKriteria.add(kriteria1);
    kriteria2= new Kriteria2("Kriteria 2", 5, 20, 13,7,18);
    listKriteria.add(kriteria2);
    kriteria3 = new Kriteria3("Kriteria 3", 3, 8, 5,4,7);
    listKriteria.add(kriteria3);

/* I want something like this:

1st 
double result= Kriteria1.lowMembership + Kriteria2.lowMembership + Kriteria3.lowMembership;
2nd
double result= Kriteria1.lowMembership + Kriteria2.lowMembership + Kriteria3.highMembership;
3rd
double result= Kriteria1.lowMembership + Kriteria2.highMembership + Kriteria3.highMembership;
and so on for each possibility...
*/

   }        
}
```

is it enough? I changed the naming and mechanism a bit to make it shorter

Comment: Could you please post some code which you have tried??

Comment: Also you could be a bit more specific about the problem you would like to solve.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate code at runtime? Or are you looking for recursion? It's rather unclear what you want to do

Comment: It might be possible to simulate the iterations of a nested loop using a single top level loop.  Yeah, please show us some code.

Comment: expected input, expected output, clues, and what you've tried including which part you're unclear of. oh well, just a clue, recursive. i bet he is doing some homeworks.

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind is using recursion to have something similar

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I've posted the code

Comment: @abbath is the code I posted good enough to explain it?

Comment: @UnholySheep Recursion if possible

Comment: @BagusTesa I tried writing the recursive logic but can't seem to find it. Yes it's a homework about DSS using FIS Tsukamoto that can solve any problem the user inputted according to the criteria they wanted.  I posted a simpler similar code there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I posted the code

Comment: Could you explain in the question what do the numbers mean? min, max; lowMembership, highMembership;

Comment: @abbath every Kriteria has its limit value which are min and max, lowMembership and highMembership is a value I'll get after some calculation called fuzzyfication, I don't put the calculation there to make it simpler since what I wanted is just the loop

Comment: Okay, but I still don't know what to do with those numbers. The number of loops depend on which number(s)? What are the limits stand for? what to do with the membership numbers in the loops? Nothing, or what? If you want to simplify please do it clearly and properly with naming the things we need to use in able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate code at runtime, for this kind of problem simply go for recursion.

```
void fun(int n)
{
     if(n==0)
         return;
     System.out.println(n);
     fun(n-1);
}
```

Comment: You can generate code at runtime, it just takes a lot of work and is most likely not what OP wants to do

Comment: sadly @UnholySheep is right, I'm looking for the recursive one. I posted the code, would you check it out? Thanks